# How to simulate crowd noise with acoustic instruments?

Tags: sound-effects, acoustics

How would I simulate the cheering, applause, and whistles of a crowd using acoustic instruments (and possibly amplification)? Preferably it would be nice to limit it to needing 1–2 musicians to perform.

Comment: “Acoustic instruments” isn't exactly specific, is it? Do you have some particular ensemble setup in mind, or can we add anything suitable, like, ratchets and air horns?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Is there a way to mute the air horn? I should have added that it should not overpower the rest of the music, as an air horn may easily do.

Comment: Considering how Ravel instrumented the people on the market place in Limoges in his rendering of Moussorgskys Pictures of an Exhibition I have some doubts, whether the achievement of maximum acoustic similarity is the most promising or most artistic approach. I don't know, whether you you referred to a french horn, but a single one is definitely not overpowering and an experienced player thoroughly able to play a decent mezzo piano without danger of the tone breaking away.

Comment: @guidot [Here's the air horn we were discussing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_horn)